# failed to install required go module in vscode go plugin

Tags: go

So i'm using asdf to manage my go version, and currently I'm using go 1.26.x, when i try to install the go plugin in vscode it is always failed to install the required plugin because of GO111MODULE='off', even though it is using `install` not `get` one. the newer installation is using `install` right. here's the below error

```
Tools environment: GOPATH=/home/unkn0wn/.asdf/installs/golang/1.21.6/packages
Installing 8 tools at /home/unkn0wn/.asdf/installs/golang/1.21.6/packages/bin
  gopls
  gotests
  gomodifytags
  impl
  goplay
  dlv
  staticcheck
  goimports

Installing golang.org/x/tools/gopls@latest FAILED
{
 "code": 1,
 "killed": false,
 "signal": null,
 "cmd": "/home/unkn0wn/.asdf/shims/go install -v golang.org/x/tools/gopls@latest",
 "stdout": "",
 "stderr": "go: modules disabled by GO111MODULE=off; see 'go help modules'\n"
}
Installing github.com/cweill/gotests/gotests@v1.6.0 FAILED
{
 "code": 1,
 "killed": false,
 "signal": null,
 "cmd": "/home/unkn0wn/.asdf/shims/go install -v github.com/cweill/gotests/gotests@v1.6.0",
 "stdout": "",
 "stderr": "go: modules disabled by GO111MODULE=off; see 'go help modules'\n"
}
Installing github.com/fatih/gomodifytags@v1.16.0 FAILED
{
 "code": 1,
 "killed": false,
 "signal": null,
 "cmd": "/home/unkn0wn/.asdf/shims/go install -v github.com/fatih/gomodifytags@v1.16.0",
 "stdout": "",
 "stderr": "go: modules disabled by GO111MODULE=off; see 'go help modules'\n"
}
Installing github.com/josharian/impl@v1.1.0 FAILED
{
 "code": 1,
 "killed": false,
 "signal": null,
 "cmd": "/home/unkn0wn/.asdf/shims/go install -v github.com/josharian/impl@v1.1.0",
 "stdout": "",
 "stderr": "go: modules disabled by GO111MODULE=off; see 'go help modules'\n"
}
Installing github.com/haya14busa/goplay/cmd/goplay@v1.0.0 FAILED
{
 "code": 1,
 "killed": false,
 "signal": null,
 "cmd": "/home/unkn0wn/.asdf/shims/go install -v github.com/haya14busa/goplay/cmd/goplay@v1.0.0",
 "stdout": "",
 "stderr": "go: modules disabled by GO111MODULE=off; see 'go help modules'\n"
}
Installing github.com/go-delve/delve/cmd/dlv@latest FAILED
{
 "code": 1,
 "killed": false,
 "signal": null,
 "cmd": "/home/unkn0wn/.asdf/shims/go install -v github.com/go-delve/delve/cmd/dlv@latest",
 "stdout": "",
 "stderr": "go: modules disabled by GO111MODULE=off; see 'go help modules'\n"
}
Installing honnef.co/go/tools/cmd/staticcheck@latest FAILED
{
 "code": 1,
 "killed": false,
 "signal": null,
 "cmd": "/home/unkn0wn/.asdf/shims/go install -v honnef.co/go/tools/cmd/staticcheck@latest",
 "stdout": "",
 "stderr": "go: modules disabled by GO111MODULE=off; see 'go help modules'\n"
}
Installing golang.org/x/tools/cmd/goimports@latest FAILED
{
 "code": 1,
 "killed": false,
 "signal": null,
 "cmd": "/home/unkn0wn/.asdf/shims/go install -v golang.org/x/tools/cmd/goimports@latest",
 "stdout": "",
 "stderr": "go: modules disabled by GO111MODULE=off; see 'go help modules'\n"
}

8 tools failed to install.

gopls: failed to install gopls(golang.org/x/tools/gopls@latest): Error: Command failed: /home/unkn0wn/.asdf/shims/go install -v golang.org/x/tools/gopls@latest
go: modules disabled by GO111MODULE=off; see 'go help modules'
 
gotests: failed to install gotests(github.com/cweill/gotests/gotests@v1.6.0): Error: Command failed: /home/unkn0wn/.asdf/shims/go install -v github.com/cweill/gotests/gotests@v1.6.0
go: modules disabled by GO111MODULE=off; see 'go help modules'
 
gomodifytags: failed to install gomodifytags(github.com/fatih/gomodifytags@v1.16.0): Error: Command failed: /home/unkn0wn/.asdf/shims/go install -v github.com/fatih/gomodifytags@v1.16.0
go: modules disabled by GO111MODULE=off; see 'go help modules'
 
impl: failed to install impl(github.com/josharian/impl@v1.1.0): Error: Command failed: /home/unkn0wn/.asdf/shims/go install -v github.com/josharian/impl@v1.1.0
go: modules disabled by GO111MODULE=off; see 'go help modules'
 
goplay: failed to install goplay(github.com/haya14busa/goplay/cmd/goplay@v1.0.0): Error: Command failed: /home/unkn0wn/.asdf/shims/go install -v github.com/haya14busa/goplay/cmd/goplay@v1.0.0
go: modules disabled by GO111MODULE=off; see 'go help modules'
 
dlv: failed to install dlv(github.com/go-delve/delve/cmd/dlv@latest): Error: Command failed: /home/unkn0wn/.asdf/shims/go install -v github.com/go-delve/delve/cmd/dlv@latest
go: modules disabled by GO111MODULE=off; see 'go help modules'
 
staticcheck: failed to install staticcheck(honnef.co/go/tools/cmd/staticcheck@latest): Error: Command failed: /home/unkn0wn/.asdf/shims/go install -v honnef.co/go/tools/cmd/staticcheck@latest
go: modules disabled by GO111MODULE=off; see 'go help modules'
 
goimports: failed to install goimports(golang.org/x/tools/cmd/goimports@latest): Error: Command failed: /home/unkn0wn/.asdf/shims/go install -v golang.org/x/tools/cmd/goimports@latest
go: modules disabled by GO111MODULE=off; see 'go help modules'
```

How do actually fix it? I have try to make `GO111MODULE='on'` using `export GO111MODULE='on'` but I have no luck

Answer (score 0):

I have the same trouble and it trouble me a long time, when i downgrade vscode Go extension to  v0.39.1, it works!